# Opencart $description adding inline styling

Tags: php, styles, opencart

I'm working on a site using Opencart. It seems as though when $description is called, inline styling is added.

On [this product page](http://ajflynn.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=61_62&product_id=55), the product description has the following inline styling added:

```
<span style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
line-height: 18px; ">
```

On [another product page](http://ajflynn.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=59&product_id=53), the span styling is:

```
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; 
font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; text-align: justify; ">
```

This really puzzles me, because they're both using /catalog/view/theme/[theme-name]/product/product.tpl and the php is :

```
<div id="product-description"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
```

On a [category page](http://ajflynn.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=61), `$description` has this styling:

```
<span style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; font-size: small; line-height:
14.545454025268555px; ">
```

Can anyone tell me where the heck this is possibly coming from?

MTIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The styling is actually coming from the editor in the administration panel. It uses TinyMCE (a JavaScript editor mimicking a rich text editor) and this will be the cause. You can see and edit this code if you click the `source` button when editing the product, in the description area

Comment: Oh thank you thank you! :-) Should've checked it earlier... *bangs head*